# Possible to concatenate radio button vars with other elements

Tags: html, coldfusion, radio-button, html-select

## Background

I have a database for my company site in which I store parts in one table and part options in another.

When the user clicks the Add to Cart button, the following sample data gets submitted (grabbed with `<cfdump>`):

```
ADDDESCRIPTION: Mass Meters
ADDPARTNUMBER: M-                         //part number minus option suffixes
ADDPRICE: 0                               //if 0 then is RFQ
FIELDNAMES:                               //form field names
OPTIONS: .5 SCCM,5M,AIR,,_,_,Standard     //part options list
```

Currently, I use a combination of `<select>` elements and checkboxes (see [Water Cooled Closed Loop: Turmoil OCO-20R Chiller - Pascal Technologies, Inc](http://www.pascaltechnologies.com/product-details.cfm?SubCategoryID=1069) for an example). Each `<select>` has the name "Options" so the values are returned as the comma delimited list you see above.

I want to be able to use radio buttons rather than `<select>` elements for lists with less than four items per part option. Obviously, the radiobuttons need separate names in order to group properly, but I need the data they submit to be inserted into the list at the appropriate position.

---

### The Problem

I have tried naming the radiobuttons as `options[#id#]` and accessing all elements as

```
<cfif qPartOptionGroups.recordcount is not 0>  <!--- There are possible options for this part --->
    <cfif not isDefined(FORM['options[]']) or qPartOptionGroups.recordcount is not ListLen(FORM['options[]'])>
        <cfset ValidForm="">
        <cfset InfoSpan="#InfoSpan#The number of options specified does not match the number of options available [#qPartOptionGroups.recordcount#] please add the item to your cart again.<br>">
    <cfelse>
```

but it throws an undefined element exception, saying `Element options[] is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope`

I'm sure it's something I've missed; any ideas?

*P.S. - If I am forced to stick with `<select>` elements then I will do so, but for UI reasons I would prefer radiobuttons.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously, the radiobuttons need separate names in order to group properly, but I need the data they submit to be inserted into the list at the appropriate position.

I do not think you can have it both ways. As long as you need separate groups, each group's value will be submitted separately. But if you named the groups sequentially ie `option_1,option_2,...` you could certainly concatenate the values on the server side. (You could also use javascript to concatenate the values and store them in a hidden field, but it sounded like you were looking for server side options, not client side)

**Form**

```
<!--- use sequentially numbered fields and store total number in hidden field --->
<input type="radio" name="option_1" ...>
<input type="radio" name="option_1" ...>

<input type="radio" name="option_2" ...>
<input type="radio" name="option_2" ...>

<input type="radio" name="option_3" ...>
<input type="radio" name="option_3" ...>

<input type="hidden" name="numberOfOptions" value="3">
```

**Action**

```
<!--- create list of selected options --->
<cfset variables.options = "">
<cfloop from="1" to="#form.numberOfOptions#" index="x">
    <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "option_"& x)>
        <cfset variables.options = listAppend(variables.options, form["option_"& x)>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

> throws an undefined element exception, saying Element options[] is
>   undefined

Side note about the original error. `IsDefined` expects the *name* of a variable. Omitting the quotes around `FORM.options[]` forces it to be evaluated first, causing the very error you are trying to prevent. Were it not for the square brackets, the correct syntax would be:

```
     <cfif IsDefined("FORM.options[]")>
```

BUT Adobe's `IsDefined` function only accepts [valid variable names](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Variables_03.html). So if your field really were named "options[]", you would need to use structKeyExists instead:

```
     <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "options[]")>
```

Comment: Oh I see. I assumed that the "options" and "options[x]" fields were both part of an array. I see they are completely differnt vars. What I need to do is test for the existence of all variables beginning with "options" and count them so I can then concatenate. However, I am beginning to suspect that although my design choice is preferred, the logic required to make it work will require too much time to implement since I am on a tight schedule.

Comment: CF10 can create arrays for elements with the same name. But since each of your buttons groups must have different names, that feature would not help you. The logic it is not quite as hard as it sounds. Just name the fields sequentially (option_1,option_2,...) and store the number of options in a hidden field. Then use the loop above to create your "list". Within the loop use structKeyExists to verify the fields exist. (See updates above)

Comment: *use structKeyExists to verify the fields exist*  -OR- use cfparam to set a default so it always exists.

Comment: Our server is shared and running CF8, so the auto-creation of arrays definitely won't help me. ;-) Renaming the fields may not work either as this is based off an existing database. 

I'm not absolutely sure, but I believe the fields are required to be in the same order that the options exist in the table. The only way to find out is to try it though, so here goes!

Comment: After spending some time working on the remainder of the site, (several months, in fact) I've revisited this question, and come to the conclusion that @Leigh is right, I can't have it both ways. I've decided to stick with `<select>` elements since I'm leaving the company, and I'll let the next poor sucker deal with the UI. (It'd be better to revise the DB to accommodate the new data format. Since I had to edit most of it by hand I could have done it, now that I think about it!)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the same name for each radio button? Since it is radio they can select only one.

Comment: Sounds like he still wants to maintain 3 separate groups of options rather than one big group ie all 11 options.

Comment: That is correct, I need several groups of radiobuttons to coexist with `<select>` elements. I may not have stated clearly enough that there are three attributes for the part option groups: _Single item per group (radiobutton or select) **OR** multiple items per group (checkboxes), 1 or more items required, and Item code is prefix in part number._ Unrelated: I'm tempted to vote your answer up just because I like your blog and you remind me of Chuck Norris. Never dreamed you'd try to answer one of my questions here!

Comment: I think I'm still confused though. It sounds like he has either a dropdown or a group of radio buttons. In either case, he wants you to be able to pick one. Is that right or am I reading him wrong? (err, you - I was mentally thinking of Leigh as I responded, but you get my point ;)

Comment: If you take a look [this page](http://www.pascaltechnologies.com/product-details.cfm?SubCategoryID=1057), you'll see I have lots of dropdown boxes. I'm trying to make the UI slightly more intuitive by removing some of the repetition. I think that using radiobuttons when only three or fewer choices exist is easier on the eyes. Does that help?

Comment: *EDIT:* Take a look at [this screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13393558/pascal_options_screenshot.png) for more info.

Comment: @Raymond - Yep - he just several "sets" of pick-only-one options. Scott - You can do that, but since you have several of those, you will need an approach like the one below.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, the order of the options in the list is important, so I would need a way to parse that. For now, I am going to leave all the options as dropdowns and make the necessary changes to the code later as I'm running out of time.

Comment: I have to say though I'm still confused as to why "just switching" to radio didn't help you. N radio options with the same name still gives you just one form variable on the server side, just as if you had used a drop down. It should have been a very simple change. I also agree that it looks better. Let me know if you get more time to work on this. I'm very curious now.

Comment: Guys, here is a [quick and dirty example](http://pastebin.com/5rcYYQtv) of what I was describing below. As long as you select the same options, the "list" generated by the old/new process should be exactly the same. If you have time, take a look. I am curious if it is at least in the ball park.

Comment: I didn't mean to abandon the question, @RaymondCamden, I have been fairly busy working on other aspects of the site. Now to answer your curiosity, when I declare **multiple** `<select>` elements (each with the same name), I get **ONE** variable returned as a comma-delimited list containing the selected `<option>` value from each `<select>`. I'd like to maintain that behavior if at all possible. That's why I'm stumped, since

Comment: ...if I use one name for all radiobutton elements they're automatically grouped together, thus only one option is ever returned. @Leigh, thanks, I'll see what that does.

_I hate the five-minute limit for edits._